# Surface Area (Integration)

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Find the surface area of the object by rotating $y = 4+3x^2$ about the $y$-axis, where $1 \leq x \leq 2$.

I've been using the formula:

Surface area: 
Definite integral of $$2\pi y\Bigg(1+\Big(\dfrac{dx}{dy}\Big)^2\Bigg)dy$$

Limits are supposed to be in the form of $y$ for the above question.

I've been trying to do this question for the last 3 hours and I get stuck at $$\int\dfrac{\cos(x)}{\sin^5(x)}dx$$

Can anyone help me how to solve the above form?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make a substitution $u = \sin(x)$

Comment: You could also write this as $\int\cot x \csc^{4}x dx$, and then substitute $u=\csc x$.

Answer (score 0):

Take $u = \sin x$ then $du = \cos x dx$. The integral becomes

$$\int \frac{ 1}{u^5} du$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $x=\sqrt{\frac{y-4}{3}}, \;\;\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{y-4}{3}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{3}\text{ and }\left(\frac{dx}{dy}\right)^2=\frac{1}{36}\frac{1}{\frac{y-4}{3}}=\frac{1}{12(y-4)}$.

Then $S=\displaystyle\int_7^{16} 2\pi\sqrt{\frac{y-4}{3}}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{12(y-4)}}dy=2\pi\int_7^{16}\sqrt{\frac{y-4}{3}}\sqrt{\frac{12y-47}{12(y-4)}}dy$,

so $\;\;S=\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{3}\int_7^{16}\sqrt{12y-47}dy$.  $\;\;\;$ (Now let $u=12y-47$.)

---

Alternatively, $S=\displaystyle\int_1^2 2\pi x\sqrt{1+36x^2}dx$,

so letting $u=1+36x^2$ and $du=72xdx$ gives
$\;\;\displaystyle S=\frac{\pi}{36}\int_{37}^{145}\sqrt{u}du$.